# Typescript module syntax

Tags: typescript

In typescript, what is the difference between these two:

```
declare module foo { ... }
```

and

```
declare namespace foo { ... }
```

From the docs I get the feeling they should be the same and the second one is preferred. However I see many .d.ts files that uses the first one which makes me unsure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are exactly the same. The keyword `module` was deprecated in favor of `namespace` in this case.

## More

This is because `module` confuses the with the concept of *file modules* : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/modules.html

Comment: I thought `module` keyword was not fully deprecated. Is it not still active in `declare module "foo" { ...}` (with quotation marks) for ambient modules? (maybe that is what you meant by "in this case")

Comment: Yes. That is what I meant with `in this case` 